# App including Google Maps crashes

Tags: android, api, google-maps, crash

Since a few days I try to create an App with a simple Google Map (using Google API V2).
I am a little bit experienced with java on desktop (win/linux), but this are my first steps into the world of android.

My first success, was "nacked" grey Google Maps - i belive the tiles weren't loaded because of key trouble ...

After a lot of posts an threads (also here - thanks 2 all!) i have now an APP which crashes on the phone :(  and still no map...

I list my Code and ask 4 help - what did i wrong?

```
package com.example.mapstests;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mapstests.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;


public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

//  private GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    private GoogleMap gMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }


     // Map wird mit Sicherheit geladen, gibts keine soll Fehlermeldung auftauchen 
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (gMap == null) {
            gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (gMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and here my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapstests"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <!-- Freigaben welche die App zum funktionieren braucht -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapstestspermission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <!-- OpenGL Unterstützung -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <permission
         android:name="com.example.mapstests.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature" 
         />


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 

        >

         <meta-data 
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapstests.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        </activity>


        <!-- Name der App und der Wert des API keys -->
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="here is my key" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#F2F5A9"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_0"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_0"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_0"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment        
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0101DF">  

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button" />
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

stuff out of logcat is missing... how can I export this log?

Comment: can you post the logcat with relevant information? I assume your api key is just hidden and not set to "here is my key" right?

Comment: I don't think you don't need two metadata tags for version.  ommit the version metadata tag in the activity.  The map api is bear to get going it could be the developer console it could be the build path.  I took me a long day to get the samples working don't give up.

Comment: NARF, got it! 

there was an old code snipet inside my java class which caused an error (mapview cannot  be casted on a fragment)


//  MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
//  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  
--> solved! I see a google map now! :) 
finally i am able to start with funnier things :D